# Unexplained Tomcat LifeCycleException when deploying

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm getting this error message when trying to deploy my webapp in Tomcat:

```
FAIL - Application at context path /skynet could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/skynet]]
```

Naturally, the first thing I did is to check `log/catalina.out` (as various other pages on this site say) but there is absolutely no information there (but the log isn't broken, there's a lot of output by other apps).

First I thought the problem might be that I apparently compiled to Java 7 but am running it on Java 6, but after fixing the compilation the problem remains.

**Environment:**

Tomcat 7.0.26

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.5) (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Is your app set to DEBUG level? What about in general? Something is failing during startup.

Comment: @DaveNewton What do you mean by app set to DEBUG level?

Comment: DEBUG logging logs more information than INFO logging, for example. More information about the startup process would be shown.

Comment: @DaveNewton That would be the case if there was any kind of logging framework at all, but this happens on a level below that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Tomcat has a logging framework, though, and your app context should be using your app's logging configuration. YMMV, but I've *never* seen a class version mismatch swallowed like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First I thought the problem might be that I apparently compiled to Java 7 but am running it on Java 6, but after fixing the compilation the problem remains.

And this turned out to be the problem after all. I failed when fixing the compilation settings. Now I fixed them for real, and the application starts.

Still, why is this not logged?

Comment: I'd be a little skeptical it wasn't, is there an app-specific log?

Comment: Yes, but that's just as empty. And what would be in it anyway? The main servlet cannot be loaded, let alone create an SLF4J Logger.